# Remove attribute from XmlDoc in database column on retrieve with t-SQL

Tags: sql, regex, xml

I have a Database table with a column named 'mapSQL'.

The value of this column contains an nvarchar value of an XML Document.

Value stored in database:

```
<root>
  <node1 attr1="foobar">
    <child1 attr1="foo">
    </child1>
  </node1>
  <node2 attr2="hello">
  </node2>
</root>
```

On Retrieve of the column from the database, I want to be able to strip out some of the node's attributes. In the above case, I want to be able to remove all the 'attr1' attributes and their values.

SQL document I want to be returned. Note all the 'attr1' attributes are gone:

```
<root>
  <node1>
    <child1>
    </child1>
  </node1>
  <node2 attr2="hello">
  </node2>
</root>
```

I found this is possible using the REPLACE function, and REGEX, however t-SQL does not support REGEX in the REPLACE function. Are there any other options?

Solution with REGEX:

```
REPLACE({0}.{1}, 'ToolTipResourseId=\"[^\"]*\"', '')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try smth like this:

```
declare @xml xml = N'<root>
  <node1 attr1="foobar">
    <child1 attr1="foo">
    </child1>
  </node1>
  <node2 attr2="hello">
  </node2>
</root>'

set @xml.modify('delete (//@*[local-name()="attr1"])')

select @xml
```

For selecting, you can create scalar funtion that gets xml value and returns cleared value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ClearXml]
(
    @Xml xml
)
RETURNS xml
AS
BEGIN
    set @Xml.modify('delete (//@*[local-name()="attr1"])')
    return @Xml
END

create table #temp (value xml)
declare @xml xml = N'<root>
  <node1 attr1="foobar">
    <child1 attr1="foo">
    </child1>
  </node1>
  <node2 attr2="hello">
  </node2>
</root>'

insert into #temp
values (@xml)

select
    dbo.ClearXml(t.value)
from #temp as t

drop table #temp
```